# Can't run eslint command within GitBash. The problem with GitBash itself?

Tags: eslint, git-bash

I have an issue with GitBash finding eslint tool.

I tried to:

1. specifying PATH through Environment Variables, didn't help.
2. adding path manually to .bash_profile file, didn't help either.
3. reinstalling eslint. Nope, no result.

Also, it works with PowerShell/Command Prompt but not with Git Bash.
And it works if I provide a full path in Git Bash:

```
$ C:\\Users\\grant\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\eslint\\bin\\eslint.js -v
v8.29.0
```

Here is the error:

```
$ eslint -v
C:\Users\grant\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

My thoughts that its something wrong with Git Bash itself... I reinstalled it as well (not absolutely completely, it still had all the login information and access to github, etc.), but nothing really changed.

What's causing this? How to fix such problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is related to nodejs, not git bash. What does `ls -la 'C:\Users\grant\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/'node*` print?

Comment: @hlovdal thanks for replying!
Here is what I get:

-rw-r--r-- 1 grant 197609       34 Dec  9 21:19 'C:\Users\grant\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node'
-rwxr-xr-x 2 grant 197609 68195960 Dec  9 21:19 'C:\Users\grant\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node.exe'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that, my global packages were being installed in different folder. And NodeJS looked them in another folder. So to fix this issue, I had to change the package installation folder with "npm config set prefix".